# How to detach a Git submodule?

Tags: git

I have a repository A with a submodule B. How to detach B from A so that the local repository of B still serves as an independent Git repository with the same remote for B as before?

I currently use (being in a local folder for A):

```
git submodule deinit B
cd B
git init
git remote add origin <REMOTE_FOR_B>
```

Is there a better way (e.g. not requiring specifying <REMOTE_FOR_B>)?

Comment: Save the URL before `deinit`: `suburl=$(cd B && exec git remote get-url origin)`; use it in `git remote add origin $suburl && unset suburl`

Comment: Perhaps you also want to ignore the ex-submodule in the superproject: `echo B >>.gitignore && git add .gitignore && git commit -m "Remove submodule \`B\`"`

Comment: You might also want to move what would normally be in a `.git` directory back into the submodule, out of where it got "absorbed" into the superproject. That's not required unless you'll be moving or removing the superproject repository: the `.git` file that the submodule system sets up refers to the absorbed repository directory by relative path, so as long as the relative path keeps working, the submodule will keep working.

Answer (score 1):

The best working version so far for me (based heavily on the suggestion by [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd)) would be (provided $FOLDER and $BRANCH are properly set):

```
suburl=$(cd $FOLDER && exec git remote get-url origin && cd ..)
git submodule deinit -f $FOLDER
cd $FOLDER
git init
git remote add origin $suburl
unset suburl
```

Optionally I also sync the local branch with the remote one using:

```
git fetch
git checkout $BRANCH
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/$BRANCH $BRANCH
```